# Filter Events By SingleValueExtendedProperties with MS Graph SDK

Tags: microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar, microsoft-graph-api

I have created an event on an Outlook calendar using the MS Graph SDK, and I have successfully added a SingleValueExtendedProperty. When I try to retrieve only those calendar events with that SingleValueExtendedProperty, the filter does not work. I do get the property back on the event I created, but I also get back other events. The .Expand seems to be working, but the filter is not. This is my query:

```
var events = await graphClient.Me.Events
            .Request()
            .Expand("SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {dae3342f-dd63-4e88-a95e-5d7d26073b3e} Name EventId')")
            .OrderBy("createdDateTime DESC")
            .GetAsync();
```

I have tried with and without HTML encoding the spaces and brackets, with the same result either way.